# What does RichTextBox.SelectedText do under the hood?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, richtextbox

I'm looking at the [SelectedText property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext.aspx) of the RichTextBox class.

If you Set the property (using `rtb.SelectedText = "someval"`), it appends the line to the control. It's useful for setting different font styles to your current line without bothering with the rest of the RTB's text.

What is it doing under the hood, though? Is it using `RichTextBox.Text +=` or `RichTextBox.AppendText()` or something else I'm unaware of? It doesn't say anywhere in the documentation that it appends text, but it does.

Any ideas? The documentation here is not very descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `SelectedText` property replaces the selected text. If nothing is selected, it inserts the text at the location of the cursor, which is at the end of the text if you haven't moved it.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `SelectedText` property, the .NET Framework converts your text into a stream of data and sends the underlying rich edit control an [`EM_STREAMIN` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774302.aspx), specifying the data format, the `SFF_SELECTION` flag, and an [`EDITSTREAM` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787891.aspx) containing additional information.

Note that most of the WinForms controls are simply wrappers around their counterparts in the Win32 API, and the `RichTextBox` is no exception. The .NET Framework is doing for you in a quick, simple, and object-oriented way what you would normally have to do by hand were you programming the Win32 API more directly.

If you're curious about this type of implementation detail, I highly recommend that you grab a copy of [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) while it is still free. It's an invaluable tool that allows you to browse the source code of .NET assemblies, including the source code for the Framework. Expand the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace and find the `RichTextBox` class. From there, locate its `SelectedText` property, and press the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar to disassemble the code. Clicking on any of the method calls will jump to the code for those methods as well. You can get a pretty clear picture of what's going on under the hood.

But remember, you're not supposed to *rely* on this type of implementation detail in writing your code. Although this particular example is unlikely to ever change, there's a *reason* that the documentation doesn't go into detail on how things are implemented under the hood. The whole point of working in a high-level environment like WinForms is that it abstracts away most of the complexity with which you would normally be forced to contend. Just write the code that makes sense.

Comment: .NET Reflector won't help much as RichTextBox is a wrapper over riched20.dll (like @Cody mentioned). So many details are not in managed world.

Comment: @Lex: Using Reflector, you can still see how the `RichTextBox` control calls down to the Windows API and its underlying native control. Granted, you don't know what `richedxx.dll` is doing once it receives the messages, but somehow I doubt that was the focus of the asker.